# In slush pool, what does a yay!!! mean when using cpuminer

Tags: mining-pools, terminology, slush

I am new to bit coins.  I an now running slush pool.  What does a yay!!! mean?  Is the number of yays a good thing?  I had more servers, I get more yay!!!!

The lib I am using:   cpuminer

```
http://www.return1.at/bitcoin-miner-ubuntu/
./minerd --url=http://api.bitcoin.cz:8332

  [2014-01-13 05:05:28] thread 0: 55109708 hashes, 1264 khash/s
   [2014-01-13 05:06:28] thread 0: 75821248 hashes, 1266 khash/s
   [2014-01-13 05:07:28] thread 0: 75957608 hashes, 1264 khash/s
   [2014-01-13 05:08:28] thread 0: 75848480 hashes, 1268 khash/s
   [2014-01-13 05:09:09] thread 0: 52297492 hashes, 1268 khash/s
   [2014-01-13 05:09:09] accepted: 9/9 (100.00%), 1268 khash/s (yay!!!)
   [2014-01-13 05:10:09] thread 0: 76107420 hashes, 1270 khash/s
   [2014-01-13 05:11:09] thread 0: 76221520 hashes, 1269 khash/s
   [2014-01-13 05:12:09] thread 0: 76115796 hashes, 1270 khash/s
   [2014-01-13 05:13:03] Stratum detected new block
```

What is the layman's explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That simply means you grabbed a new share from the pool.  In this case the share has a difficulty of 9, so it's essentially 9 shares at a difficulty of 1.